# Session Management OpenID Connect Why two Iframes?

Tags: session, openid-connect

I have been reading the OpenID Connect draft specification describing how to handle a user log off. Everything points to this super weird, two iframe solution. See here:
[openid spec for sessions](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#CreatingUpdatingSessions)
and a brief description here:
[Hans Zandbelt blog regarding this strategy](https://hanszandbelt.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/openid-connect-session-management/)

can someone explain why I need two separate iframes, and not just one to the openid identity provider, and some javascript on my page to delete the cookie and redirect to the sso login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger for the deletion of your local session lives in a different domain i.e. the OpenID Connect Provider's domain. So to learn about the changes happening there you need to "poll" the Provider which involves so-called "cross-domain" communication. To avoid polling a remote URL constantly with a large network traffic overhead, the idea is that you poll for a state change locally by checking the Provider's cookie. That is done by leveraging the postMessage communication framework between iframes because only code presented by the OP can check the OP's cookie.

Comment: One point of clarification: Why two iframes? I know one has to be used to hit a page on the OP server, and check if the cookie exists, but the second iframe doesn't seem relevant... The first iframe can call its parent window callback, then the main page can delete the cookie and do a javascript redirect to the login page, right?

Comment: Thanks Hans! I bet I will be attempting this soon, but not today. just got coerced to do server polling. hooray....

Comment: is there any implementation examples that could be looked in ?

Comment: This answer is currently the accepted one, but unless I'm missing something, it doesn't address the need for 2 iframes, or more specifically the RP iframe. Like Nathan said, you could implement the polling mechanism without an RP iframe. The answer below from @leonardo-chaia does explain it: the spec calls for a silent refresh if the session state changes. So I guess you could implement the polling in the parent window, while putting the refresh logic in the RP iframe (or reuse an existing silent refresh iframe). This is what Manfred Steyer's angular-oauth2-oidc library does, for example.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same doubts the other day about why we need two iframes to perform session check. From my point of viewing it, the RP iframe was totally useless. As a matter of fact, it's totally possible to perform the session check with just an iframe pointing to the `check_session_iframe` url.

The thing is that, when you receive the `changed` message, you will most likely want to attempt a silent token renewal, as the spec says, and you will need an iframe for doing so, hence the RP iframe.

The [spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) (4.1 RP Iframe) says:

```
Upon receipt of changed, the RP MUST perform re-authentication with 
prompt=none to obtain the current session state at the OP. 

When the RP detects a session state change, it SHOULD first try a prompt=none 
request within an iframe to obtain a new ID Token and session state, sending 
the old ID Token as the id_token_hint.
```

I believe the RP iframe is responsible for performing the silent token renewal, upon the receive of a changed message. The RP iframe should then generate a new token request with prompt=none, hence the silently part.
If the RP iframe fails to silently renew the token, then the user is no longer authenticated, and your application should be notified to perform proper actions.